# Error while mounting a USB device

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdc2: Command-line `mount "/mnt/pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part2"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: block device /dev/sdc2 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

`dmesg | tail` gives the following output :

```
[ 1520.034123] EXT4-fs (sdc2): write access unavailable, cannot proceed
```

I am receiving this error for quite some time and i cannot find a way to remove the write protection on the disk.

Comment: Is this an USB drive with write-protection switch on the case? Some devices have such a small switch and if one does not know it's easy to miss them.

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same problem, an you could try enter this in the terminal:

```
sudo umount -a
sudo mount /dev/sdc2 /media
sudo mount -a
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: And why would that help?